# Why C# DateTime fails to convert right Secs From Epoch obtained in C++?

Tags: c#, c++, time

I have a C++ method that finds the last modified time of a file.
That method computes a double representing the #of seconds from epoch.

I'm using the following algorithm:

```
const HANDLE handle = CreateFile(filePath.c_str(), // file to open
                                     GENERIC_READ,     // open for reading
                                     FILE_SHARE_READ,  // share for reading
                                     nullptr,          // default security
                                     OPEN_EXISTING,    // Open existing file only if it exists, and only intact.
                                     FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
                                     nullptr); // no attr.
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == handle)
{
    ThrowWindowsErrorMessage(__CODE_LOCATION__);
}

if (BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION fileInformation; 0 == GetFileInformationByHandle(handle, &fileInformation))
{
    ThrowWindowsErrorMessage(__CODE_LOCATION__);
}
else
{
    SYSTEMTIME systemTime;
    if (0 == FileTimeToSystemTime(&fileInformation.ftLastWriteTime, &systemTime))
    {
        ThrowWindowsErrorMessage(__CODE_LOCATION__);
    }
    else
    {
        tm tim = {0};
        tim.tm_sec = systemTime.wSecond;
        tim.tm_min = systemTime.wMinute;
        tim.tm_hour = systemTime.wHour;
        tim.tm_mday = systemTime.wDay;
        tim.tm_mon = systemTime.wMonth - 1;
        tim.tm_year = systemTime.wYear - 1900;
 
        // daylight time applies or not.
        tim.tm_isdst = -1;

        const time_t t0 = mktime(&tim);
        if (static_cast<time_t>(-1) != t0)
        {
            tTime = t0;
        }
    }
}
CloseHandle(handle);
return tTime;
```

Running this code against a file with the following details:

[image]

is given me the following fields in `systemTime`:

[image]

Which is correct, as I'm on a +2h time zone difference from UTC. (so last modified time of 9:35am is indeed 7:35am UTC)

The Value of `tTime` return is `1667453701` which is the number of seconds from 1st-Jan-1970 (epoch).

Now on C#, i'm trying to construct a `DateTime` object that represent the last modified file time in UTC by doing the following code (of course in my actual program, the return value is used, but here is just an example):

```
var lastModifiedFileTime = new DateTime(1970, 1,1).AddSeconds(1667453701);
```

The `lastModifiedFileTime` is as the following:

[image]

As you can see, everything is fine except a +2h difference. C# shows the time as 5:35am
As I tried to normalize the measurements to UTC time zone, i would expect to have the same values.

What is the problem here? and how can I fix it?

Comment: probably just need to set the kind to UTC

Comment: @AlanBirtles: how to do it?

Comment: Call the constructor with a DateTimeKind like `new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(1667453701)` or use DateTimeOffset  instead like `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(1667453701).UtcDateTime`

Comment: @Ralf: Trying both on https://dotnetfiddle.net/ - i got the same 5:35am

Comment: According to https://www.unixtimestamp.com/ 5:35 is correct for that timestamp